# Display a comma separated list as a numbered list on html page

Tags: arrays, laravel, html-lists

I am creating a foodlog application in Laravel and the instructions on how to make a recipe is stored in a comma separated list in the database as so:

```
cook the chicken, add peppers and onions, add sauce, serve with rice
```

I would like to make this appear as a numbered list on my website like:

```
1. cook the chicken
2. add peppers and onions
3. add sauce
4. serve with rice
```

I currently have the string appearing in a '< p >' tag but would like it as a numbered list.  Any ideas?

**info.blade.php**

```
<h1>{{ $recipes->recipe_name }}<h1>
<h2>Ingredients:</h2> <p>{{ $recipes->ingredients}}</p><br>
<h2>How to:</h2> <p>{{ $recipes->description }}</p><br>
```

**RecipesController.php**

```
public function showinfo($id) {     
    $recipes = Recipes::find($id);
    return view('recipes.info', compact('recipes'));
}
```

Appearing like so:
[image: How it is currently being displayed]

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

**info.blade.php**

```
$descriptionList = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection(explode(",", $description));

echo "<ol>";
$descriptionList->each(function($description){
     echo "<li>" . $description . "</li>";
});
echo "</ol>";
```

or

```
$description = "cook the chicken, add peppers and onions, add sauce, serve with rice";

$descriptionList = explode(",", $description);
<ol>  
    @foreach ($descriptionList as $descriptionItem)
       <li>{{ $descriptionItem }}</li>
    @endforeach    
</ol>
```

You can convert this to using the Laravel blade template.

Comment: Nice recipe: `Prevent xss, <script>alert('xss')</alert>, Whoops`. Please be aware that this first implementation is vulnerable for xss attack. Blade automatically escapes the output to prevent this. Please use the second implementation!